# Angular 2. CanActivate is called on load only

Tags: angular

I have the following routing that I import to Application Component:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: MainLayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '', redirectTo: 'main', pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'main', loadChildren: 'app/main/main.module#MaindModule'
      },
      {
        path: 'cars', loadChildren: 'app/cars/cars.module#CarsModule'
      }  
    ],
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]    
  },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    component: EmptyLayoutComponent,
    loadChildren: 'app/auth/auth.module#AuthModule'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'main'
  }
];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

As you can see I have `canActivate`. I noticed that `AuthGuard` is called when I open application in first time or write address in the browser, but if I use my menu to change url then `AuthGuard` is not called:

```
 <a routerLink="/cars">
```

What I have done wrong?

AuthGuard:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService,
              private router: Router) {}

  canActivate() {
    if (!this.authService.authenticated) {
      this.router.navigate(['/auth/login']);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Code of `AuthGuard` ?

Comment: @TouqeerShafi I don't think that it's related to AuthGuard itself, but I have updated the question.

Comment: Perhaps [`canActivateChild`](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivateChild) does what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that `CanActivate` is only set on the parent empty route. If you want it to execute again when navigating between child routes, consider using `canActivateChild` instead.